# Best way to obtain a scrollable OpenGL view with Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

Say I'm writing a 2D cad program of some sort, and I want to be able to zoom in and scroll around my document. However, I also want full control over how my document is drawn and I want an OpenGL context for which to do the drawing. How do I do this? Should I subclass NSScrollView and do something I can't quite figure out there? Should I subclass NSOpenGLView and add a pair of NSScrollers and figure out how to draw them properly? Making NSScrollers and drawing them in a way that looks good natively looks nontrivial, but NSScrollViews seem to want to own all the content you might be scrolling, rather than letting me control the size of the knob of the scroll bar and other such things. I'd be completely content with giving a document size in pixels or some such, just the most important thing to me is that when I draw to (0,0) in my OpenGL context, I draw to the corner of the window, and not into some buffer that NSScrollView owns.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I subclass NSOpenGLView and add a pair of NSScrollers

Yes, since scrolling a OpenGL view doesn't make sense. You want to adjust the viewing volume (i.e. the parameters defining the projection matrix), rather than moving your viewport around. And that only works if you have manual control over the scroll bars.